# In unity3d, how to use a class's father's valuables in this class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making some C# scripts for the ammo in my tank game.

I just found that for all kinds of ammo, like shell and rocket, always got some similar points, like damage and range. So what I want to do is first writing a script called Ammo, holding all the similar points, then build two scripts called Shell and Rocket, as children classes of Ammo class. Then I can reuse the similar valuables in Ammo class. However, C# doesn't allow me to do that. Specifically, Rocket and Shell class don't get the access to the valuables in Ammo class.

How could I fix it up?

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking but C# certainly does support inheritance

Comment: Would you be able to post some code snippets? Might just be a simple protection issue because @Sayse is correct. I've done pretty much the same setup in unity and it certainly works

Comment: http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/scripting/inheritance

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `private`, mark the variables as `protected` (or `public`).

If the variables/functions are not marked as `public/private/protected`, you can just add `protected` to the beginning, like this:

```
protected int m_Health = 100;
```